localization/orientation issue while running robot localization with navsat transform node for fusing GPS + IMU in rviz visualization
I'm trying to use the robot localization package with the navsat transform node for gps+imu sensor fusion. My system is Ubuntu 20.04 and ros-noetic. I know this configuration will not produce the best results, but wanted to make this implementation work first and then move on to add some odometry data from the laser_scan_matcher with a dual ekf setup (local and global). The implementation seems to be working up to a point, but in Rviz there is a missmatch in the frames/orientation of the robot. The algorithm tracks down perfectly the shape of the movement, a square test, and it also tracks down the 90 degrees turns. My problem is that the orientation output of the filtered_map topic which is the final global localization output of the robot doesn't seem to be working and the orientation part is completely the same as the (raw) imu data I'm fusing in the system. It doesn't do anything to align the orientation im giving to the filter with the global ENU frame. Right now my imu raw data is showing 0 in the north, but after using the correct magnetic declination rate and applying the yaw offset in rviz i cant make it show 0 in the global east. Still the odometry/filtered_map.orientation (output of the rl node) is identical with the raw imu data I'm feeding in the rl node. I know this configuration won't produce the best results in terms of continuity but i just want to test it and move on from having this setup working correctly. Here are my launch and config files. Basically I'm providing a static transform to align map and odom frames and I'm asking from the rl node ekf_se_map to provide me the odom <-> base_link transform.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find cmd2twist)/config/ekf_map_only.yaml" />
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find cmd2twist)/config/navsat_params.yaml" />
  
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_map" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_imu_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link ext_imu" />
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="gps" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link gps" />
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="mapodomtf" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 map odom" />
  
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" clear_params="true" output="screen">
      <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
      <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/fix"/>
      <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu/data"/>
  </node>

</launch>


ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 10
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: true
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false
  publish_tf: true

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: odom

# -------------------------------------
# GPS signal:
  odom0: /odometry/gps
  odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false,  false,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false
  odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5

  imu0: /imu/data
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false,  false, true,
                false, false, false,
                false, false, true,
                false,  false,  false] 
  imu0_nodelay: true
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false

  process_noise_covariance: [10.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    10.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-10,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1e-10,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]


navsat_transform:
  frequency: 10
  delay: 0.0
  magnetic_declination_radians: 0.08864631991
  yaw_offset: 1.5707963  #IMPORTANT IF OUR IMU HAS 0 HEADING LOOKING NORTH !!! navsat_transform_node has 0 when facing east
  zero_altitude: true
  broadcast_cartasian_transform: true
  broadcast_utm_transform: false
  broadcast_utm_transform_as_parent_frame: false
  publish_filtered_gps: false
  use_odometry_yaw: false
  wait_for_datum: false


Here are the results in rviz.

As you can see it does a pretty good job in this movement in terms of position, it even ends in the same origin, but in terms of orientation it is completely off. (For now the drift of the imu is irrelevant, the main point is that it doesn't move correctly, doesn't move in the x direction when going forward etc.) The main problem is that the result of the orientation of the filtered_map is the same as the raw imu input and that causes issues in the final result, as you can see in the pic (just a small test plot, not smth relevant).

Also the terminal output of the rl node is shown here with the inital transform.

Orientation is essential for next steps to navigate along some waypoints as the orientation must be known for navigating there correctly. Is there something wrong with my setup and the orientation isn't fused properly? Thank you very much in advance and sorry for the long message.
EDIT 1
So, I think that the results are correct that way and the orientation should indeed be the output of the imu since there is no other source of orientation fused. I think that the visualization in rviz will always be in respect to the ENU frame and this wont be a problem later for navigation. It all comes down to the alignment of the robots' orientation with the ENU frame. If this is set correctly then the movement/orientation relation makes sense. My main problem now is that this relation isn't always on point and i have some runs where the robot moves indeed to the correct direction but others that it doesnt. I still am not sure why this is the case. Can this be caused due to wrong initial IMU message? Is there a way to assure that the transformation will be correct.
Nevertheless, the movement depicted makes sense and the map frame correctly depicts the ENU frame (x going up when robot moves to the north, y going up when robot going east). This can also be seen in the graph for a rectangle movement.

and the recorded topics:

Of course the results are as good as the inputs, so i will try testing with laser odometry to include a continuous source and see the results.
Is there any other way to guarantee the ENU robot's orientation transformation? The main thing is that everything works, when providing a navigation goal. The GPS coordinates <-> map transformation seems to be working with the fromLL service provided by navsat.
EDIT 2
I extended the implementation to include lidar measurements and extended it to a dual ekf setup. The first, fusing:

pose_stamped (pose with covariance msg) x,y,yaw
IMU (yaw, wz)
cmd_vel (twist with covariance msg) vx, wz (as the robot can only take velocity commands in x or yaw vel.

sends the base_link <-> odom transform while the second one fuses:

odometry/gps (output of navsat node) x,y
pose_stamped (as 1st instance) DIFFERENTIAL mode, x,y
IMU (yaw, wz)
cmd_vel (twist with covariance msg) vx, wz

and broadcasts the map <-> odom transform.
this can also be seen in the yaml file.
  # For parameter descriptions, please refer to the template parameter files for each node.

ekf_se_odom: # Used only for broadcasting odom to base_link transforms
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: true
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false
  publish_tf: true

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_footprint
  #base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: odom
  
  twist0: /cmd_vel

  twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true,  true,  false,
                 false, false, true,
                 false, false, false]
  twist0_queue_size: 10
  twist0_nodelay: true
  twist0_differential: false
  twist0_relative: false
  #twist0_rejection_threshold: 2

# -------------------------------------
# Laser scanmatching odometry:

  pose0: /laser_pose
  pose0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, true,
                 false,  false,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  pose0_queue_size: 10
  pose0_nodelay: true
  pose0_differential: false
  pose0_relative: false
  #pose0_rejection_threshold: 5


# --------------------------------------
# imu configure:

  imu0: /imu/data
  #imu0: /imu
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false,  false,  false]
  imu0_nodelay: true
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: fals
  
  process_noise_covariance: [1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]


ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: true
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false
  publish_tf: true

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_footprint
  #base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: map

# -------------------------------------
# GPS signal:
  odom0: /odometry/gps
  odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false,  false,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false
  #odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 3

# -------------------------------------

  pose0: /laser_pose
  pose0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false,  false,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  pose0_queue_size: 10
  pose0_nodelay: true
  pose0_differential: true
  pose0_relative: false

  twist0: /cmd_vel
  
  twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true,  true,  false,
                 false, false, true,
                 false, false, false]
  twist0_queue_size: 10
  twist0_nodelay: true
  twist0_differential: false
  twist0_relative: false


  imu0: /imu/data
  #imu0: /imu
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false,  false,  false]
  imu0_nodelay: true
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false

    
    
    process_noise_covariance: [1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                             0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

  
  initial_estimate_covariance: [1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]


the navsat subscribes to the /fix /imu/data and odometry/filtered_map topic from the 2nd ekf instance as seen in the launch file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

<node pkg="cmd2twist" type="cmd2twist" name="cmd_vel_to_twist_node" output="screen" />
<node pkg="cmd2twist" type="accfilter" name="accFilter" output="screen" />
<node pkg="cmd2twist" type="laserpose" name="laserPose" output="screen" />
<node pkg="cmd2twist" type="gps_filter_node" name="gps_filter_node" output="screen" />

 <rosparam command="load" file="$(find cmd2twist)/config/ekf_vel.yaml" />
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find cmd2twist)/config/navsat_params.yaml" />

 <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_odom" clear_params="true"/>

 <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_map" clear_params="true">
   <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
 </node>

 <!--node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_imu_broadcaster" args="0 0 0.35 0 0 0 1 base_link ext_imu" /-->
 <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_imu_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link ext_imu" />

 <!--node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="gps" args="0 0 0.2 0 0 0 1 base_footprint gps" /-->
 <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="gps" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link gps" />

 <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" clear_params="true" output="screen">
     <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
     <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/fix"/>
     <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu/data"/>
 </node>



</launch>

The result looks pretty solid in rviz, still it only moves with respect to the ENU frame, but I'm not entirely sure if the fusion of the laser odometry and the gps coordinates make sense, as i can see different behaviour in the output of the lidar odometry and the gps localization. However I'm quite happy with the total result in rviz.

and here as a gif. The movement corresponds nicely to the actual movement of the robot.

My main issue now is that i can't yet tackle big jumps coming from the gps data, as I cant think of a recovery behaviour when the gps signal is lost or the rtk communication with the gps base, as can be seen in the lat/long plots. In that case there are big jumps in the localization.

Anyway I don't think i should really focus on that case, as in order to fuse the gps properly i need to fix the gps data and not have so big jumps in there. (either problem with reliability of current gps module NS-HP-GN5, or the radio communication between rover and base or even the current testing location). I'm just concerned now if both ekfs work as intended.
One thing that also strongly concerns me is that the odom and map frame have quite a difference in rviz visualization and the odom frame keeps moving, which i cant quite understand. I know that this transformation should compensate for drift but it moves quite a lot and not in a smooth way. It can be seen in the following picture.

So I'm wandering if this configuration could work and if I'm fusing odometry with IMU and the gps data in a correct way. The visualization looks quite well as long as the gps stream is stable. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Hi did you find the solution? I am facing similar issue here: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/112056/gps-and-navsat-transform-node-issues-with-magnetic-declination-and-yaw-offset-in
I imagine that there is some issues in rl code ?

It's not clear what exact questions you have that you'd like to have answered at this point. Looking at your most recent configuration, I spot the following issues:

In your odom-frame EKF instance, you have this configuration:

  pose0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, true,
                 false,  false,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]

  ...

  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false,  false,  false]

What you are telling the filter is that you want to fuse absolute yaw from both your scan matcher AND your IMU. But those aren't going to agree with each other. I don't see any sample messages, so I don't know if you are reporting those messages in a different frame and supplying a transform so the EKF gets a consistent view, but that would be hard to do with something like a scan matcher. Anyway, your scan matcher's yaw will come from integrated scan matches, and your IMU yaw will come from a magnetometer.
Even if you tried to just fuse yaw from the IMU and X/Y position from the scan matcher, though, you will have trouble, because the scan matcher might say you went from (0, 0) to (1, 0), which implies a yaw of 0, but the IMU might give a yaw of, e.g., pi / 3 radians. In that event, your robot will appear to move sideways.
If it were me, I'd fuse the absolute pose (x, y, and yaw) from the scan matcher, and turn on relative for the IMU data. Or fuse x, y, and yaw velocity from the scan matcher, if it produces it, though you still won't want to use absolute yaw from the IMU then.

You actually are creating the issue I described above with your map frame EKF, and compounding it with another issue. Here are your sensor configs:

  odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false,  false,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]

  ...

  pose0: /laser_pose
  pose0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false,  false,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  
  ...

  twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true,  true,  false,
                 false, false, true,
                 false, false, false]

  ...

  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false,  false,  false]

You can see that you are fusing absolute X and Y position from your GPS and scan matcher. The filter is just going to jump back and forth between them as the measurements arrive (again, unless you have those sensor messages in different frames and are supplying a transform to your world frame - this is why I ask people to include sample messages from every sensor input).
You are only using yaw from your IMU, but that still causes the problem I mentioned in (1), which is that the perceived direction of travel won't match the orientation of your robot.

Thank you very much for taking time to read and answer my question. I thought that i would solve the problem you described in (2) (position x,y data from different sources) by setting the deferential option from the odom source (scanmatcher node) to true. I thought that with this option the filter uses the estimated velocity from 2 sequential position measurements. Concerning the (1) point i enabled the use_imu parameter of the laser_scan_matcher node, so it already uses the imu in the orientation estimation and i think that as i tried to show with the graphs the orientation output of the(1/3)

ekf is exactly identical with the orientation output of the IMU. Still its redundant to fuse it twice and maybe not correct practice but i dont think it causes issues now. The only think i am concerned was if the pose estimation from the laser scan matcher is "alligned" with the actual movement of the robot and also about the difference in the map-odom frame, which i know is expected but sometimes it gets big. I think though that overall the filter works as intended as i can see in rviz the actual movement of the robot (at least in relation to the ENU frame). (2/3)

I am planning to upgrade my hardware (gps sensor or radio communication between rtk rover/base, imu and maybe try another odometry source) and then test everything again. I just wanted to be sure that everything is well aligned. (forward movement is shown both from scan_matcher and navsat node). Thats what still troubles me and if the correct behavior Im seeing from the filter is actually the correct result or just the "confidence" put on the gps data, outweighs the other sources for position estimation. Thanks in advance and i will try to remove redundant or duplicate sensor information (3/3)

Hi @aimpet which IMU sensor are you using? Does it have a magnetomer? I have marked you on my question on this regard, since automaton replied me there too and it seems I need a new source of IMU data referenced to earth.

Hello @MarcusVinicius. So, yes you do need some reference concerning the ENU frame so an IMU with magnetometer could be a solution. I used the PhidgetSpatial Precision 3/3/3 IMU, which contains a magnetometer and i could use the madgwick filter to get 0 yaw when facing magnetic north. However i had issues with drift and false linear acceleration measurements from the specific IMU. I wanted to try with a new set of hardware now, mainly new gps and imu sensors. I'll update when i test them. So, basically you need an imu with magnetometer or a compass to provide some earth-referenced yaw value.
